# How to create a UI in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, raw-input

So I have the code...

```
name = raw_input("Full Name: ")
```

And that is supposed to allow me to type in a name and then use that name to activate certain "if" statements. However, I want to have the program open a window, like a very simple GUI, where I can type the word. My only experience with creating a GUI is in Java and through Processing, so I am very lost when it comes to Python. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you try https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html?

Comment: I did not, thank you.

Comment: Did you try Googling "python gui"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For start i suggest for you to start with Tkinter library (built in library).

This is a simple program using Tkinter gui.

```
import Tkinter

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
        self.entryVariable.set(u"Enter text here.")

        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Click me !",
                                command=self.OnButtonClick)
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)

        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,
                              anchor="w",fg="white",bg="blue")
        label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable.set(u"Hello !")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())       
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnButtonClick(self):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (You clicked the button)" )
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (You pressed ENTER)" )
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```

The code taken from http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/ , i like their tutorial.

Comment: This looks good, thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Tkinter is a great way to build a quick GUI but it should be clarified that Tkinter itself is not a part of Python. The Tkinter module in Python is the built in interface to the TKinter GUI toolkit which is installed separately. Additionally - any computer on which you would like to run this program will need to have Tkinter installed in addition to Python.

EDIT: This is true if you're developing on Linux. If you're using Windows or Mac, tcl/tk is bundled into the Python installer so it IS the automagical Python solution.

TL;DR: Tkinter is a great way to start but isn't the automagical Python solution.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html to get started with Tk

Comment: Tkinter is part of Python. Tk is part of Tcl. Tkinter is included by default in most Python installations.

Comment: From the Python docs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html - first line - "The Tkinter module (“Tk interface”) is the standard Python interface to the Tk GUI toolkit. Both Tk and Tkinter are available on most Unix platforms, as well as on Windows systems. (Tk itself is not part of Python; it is maintained at ActiveState.)" - I would ask you to kindly remove your downvote.

Comment: Read that quote more carefully: "Tk itself is not part of Python." That is accurate. However, Tkinter, Python's interface to Tk, is part of Python.

Comment: My apologies, sir, it seems we're both right. On Windows and Mac, tcl/tk is included. On Linux, tcl/tk requires a separate installation. I spoke from a position of Linux experience. Wasn't aware it was included in the other two. - Edited my answer. http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/How_to_install_Tkinter for reference